Is this "eggshell" paint tinted correctly?
I applied touch up paint along a stairwell I got a like for like match with an old tin that was used for the original coat. This paint has been curing for over 4 hours and yet still has a lot of sheen to it. The touch up can I bought sat for a month, but I mixed it thoroughly with a paddle on my drill for almost five minutes. Is the glossiness going to go away?


You usually want to match with a paint chip from the wall.  Paint fades, gets dirty on walls, so exact paint can/shade match, will not match wall paint after a while.

How was the original paint applied, and how did you apply the touch up? If the answer is "roller" and "brush", the different texture left by the tool could be the issue. My trick is brushing on the touch up, and then going over the patch with a slightly water damp roller, going beyond the area of fresh paint.

@EliIser the original paint application method is a mystery that left with the prior owners. I would guess roller and indeed I used a brush. The original paint is over 10 years old. I have not had an issue brushing to touch up rolled paint that is newer.

It is expected that the color, luster and texture will not exactly match even when the same paint code is used for touching up. How noticeable this is depends on various factors, one of them being how long the existing paint has been on the wall. It will change over time (fade from light and other exposures, get dusty and dirty, just "age", etc).
You could have potentially improved the situation a little by cutting out a sample to bring in to the store - they typically have devices that can scan the color and mix based on that rather than the original code. This would allow you to match your current color instead of the color when the wall was first painted.
Standard practice when touching up spots on a wall with color matched paint is to re-paint the wall at least "corner to corner" to make this effect less obvious.

Even when the same paint can is used, years later.  Probably best to get a new can for the corner-to-corner repaint—seems the sheen is the offending issue and that won't go away unless a new can is used.

I am the father of two boys, so touching up trim and walls are something I do quite a bit.  I uses a Microlon roller for larger areas, and a natural sea sponge for smaller.  I first lay down a heavy coat of primer to help match the rolled induced orange peel effect.  The extra gloss of the patches is impossible to avoid as it is a build up of material that creates that sheen.  The best remedy I have found is to rub the patches with a damp microfiber towel or a Mr. Clean eraser to try to dull the sheen.
